# elasticsearch: How to interpret log file (cluster went to yellow status)?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS, 8GB RAM, 2 node cluster.

We posted the whole log here: http://pastebin.com/zc2iG2q4

When we look at /_cluster/health  , we see 2 unassigned shards:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch-prod",
  "status" : "yellow",    <--------------------------
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 8,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 2,    <--------------------------
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
```

In the log, we see:

```
marking and sending shard failed due to [failed to create shard]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

And other errors.

The only memory related config value we have is:

```
indices.fielddata.cache.size:  75%
```

We are looking to:

- understand the log more completely
- understand what action we need to take to address the situation now (recover) and prevent it in the future

---

Additional details:

1) ES_HEAP_SIZE is stock, no changes. (Further, looking around, it is not clear where best to change it.... `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` ?)

2) Our jvm stats are below.  (And please note, as a test, I modded `"/etc/init.d/elasticsearch"` and and added export `ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g` [in place of the existing `"export ES_HEAP_SIZE"` line] and restarted ES.... Comparing two identical nodes, one with the changed `elasticsearch` file, and one stock, the values below appear identical)

```
  "jvm" : {
    "timestamp" : 1448395039780,
    "uptime_in_millis" : 228297,
    "mem" : {
      "heap_used_in_bytes" : 81418872,
      "heap_used_percent" : 7,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 259522560,
      "heap_max_in_bytes" : 1037959168,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 50733680,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 51470336,
      "pools" : {
        "young" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 52283368,
          "max_in_bytes" : 286326784,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 71630848,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 286326784
        },
        "survivor" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 2726824,
          "max_in_bytes" : 35782656,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 8912896,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 35782656
        },
        "old" : {
          "used_in_bytes" : 26408680,
          "max_in_bytes" : 715849728,
          "peak_used_in_bytes" : 26408680,
          "peak_max_in_bytes" : 715849728
        }
      }
    },
    "threads" : {
      "count" : 81,
      "peak_count" : 81
    },
    "gc" : {
      "collectors" : {
        "young" : {
          "collection_count" : 250,
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 477
        },
        "old" : {
          "collection_count" : 1,
          "collection_time_in_millis" : 22
        }
      }
    },
    "buffer_pools" : {
      "direct" : {
        "count" : 112,
        "used_in_bytes" : 20205138,
        "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 20205138
      },
      "mapped" : {
        "count" : 0,
        "used_in_bytes" : 0,
        "total_capacity_in_bytes" : 0
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: What's your `ES_HEAP_SIZE` env variable set to?

Comment: @21zoo Good questions. OP significantly enhanced to answer your question.

Comment: @21zoo Thank you for the pointer. Problem solved. Solution posted to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The key here is the error `"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"`

Another day, another gem from the ES docs:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html

says (emphasis mine):

*The default installation of Elasticsearch is configured with a 1 GB heap. **For just about every deployment, this number is far too small.** If you are using the default heap values, your cluster is probably configured incorrectly.*

Resolution:

Edit: `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`

Set `ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g`   // this system has 8GB RAM

Restart ES

And tada.... the unassigned shards are magically assigned, and the cluster goes green.